# Unsigned char 1's complement in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, unsigned, complement

Suppose I have the following code:

```
unsigned char c = 0;
printf("%u\n", ~c);
```

GCC prints the value `4294967295`, means it prints the value of `ULONG_MAX`.

**C11 6.3.1.3 Signed and unsigned integers:**

> 1. When a value with integer type is converted to another integer type other than `_Bool`, if the value can be represented by the new
>      type, it is unchanged.
> 2. Otherwise, **if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or subtracting one more than the maximum value that
>      can be represented in the new type until the value is in the range of
>      the new type**.60)
> 3. Otherwise, the new type is signed and the value cannot be represented in it; either the result is implementation-defined or an
>      implementation-defined signal is raised.

So, `c` is promoted to `unsigned int` before applying operator `~`. Thus the
result is the one's complement of `0u`. Am I right? or is it undefined?

Comment: Shall we assume you meant `x` and not `c`, or vice versa? And fyi, that's a variadic argument list, and [things are a little different](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/variadic_arguments).

Answer (score 4):

C does not perform arithmetic in (unsigned) `char` types.  All arguments are promoted first, according to the integer promotions.  `unsigned char` promotes to `int`, so the result of `~x` is -1.  You then print this value as an *unsigned* `int`, which gives the output you observed.